# How can I convert a Matillion Job variable of type DateTime to a python datetime.datetime?

Tags: matillion

I have a Job variable `last_updated` of type `DateTime`. I'm trying to use it from a `Python Script` component, I thought it will show up as `datetime.datetime` object in python but it isn't :

```
print(latest_updated) # Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 2000
print(latest_updated.getClass()) # <type 'com.matillion.bi.emerald.server.scripting.MatillionDate'>
```

From what I see it seems to be a python bridge to some a Java's object of type `MatillionDate`.

How can I convert this to a regular `datetime.datetime` object?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what python interpreter you use:

## Jython:

If you use Jython, then the Job variable of type DateTime are, as mentioned, instances of `MatillionDate` and not `datetime`.  You can convert it back to `datetime.datetime`, by converting it to a Java's `Instant`, getting the ISO 8601 representation and parsing that:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

as_iso_string = str(latest_updated.toInstant()) # 2000-01-01T00:00:00Z
asdt = parse(as_iso_string) # datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())) tzinfo should be tzutc() not tzlocal()
asdt = parse(as_iso_string).replace(tzinfo=None) # naive datetime
asdt = parse(as_iso_string).replace(tzinfo=tzutc()) # datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Make sure that you get the timezone right, if your Job variable was meant to be in UTC you will need to do `.replace(tzinfo=tzutc())` as for some reason `dateutil.parser.parse()` in Jython is not parsing the `Z` as timezone UTC (it does in regular python 2.7.12)

## Python 2 / Python 3:

The variable would have the right type already `datetime.datetime`. No timezone

```
print(repr(latest_updated)) # datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```